# Forcing Windows to display Helvetica instead of Arial

Tags: css, fonts

How do I make it so Windows will always show Helvetica instead of Arial? Is this even possible? I know it automatically substitutes it, but is there any way to do this.

I know that I could use font squirrel but apparently that is illegal. Is there another solution?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "force?" If the user just plain doesn't have Helvetica *and* you haven't embedded it, what are you expecting to happen? (It's available for web use through [Linotype's own service](http://www.fonts.com/search/web-fonts?searchtext=helvetica&SearchIn=web-fonts#product_top), which is likely why it may be blacklisted at FontSquirrel.) Other than that, fonts are used in the order you list them in your font-family rules. So put Helvetica first; if it's available it'll be used in preference to Arial.

Comment: @scarhand : Currently windows is forcing replace of Helvetica by Arial. Changing this behaviour requires removing some keys in the registry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot. Even embedding a font would not *force* anything, since settings in the user’s system may prevent the use of downloadable fonts. Besides, embedding Helvetica *is* illegal, unless permitted by its copyright holder.

If you declare `font-family: Helvetica`, then Helvetica will be used only if the user’s system has Helvetica installed, and Windows systems usually don’t. Due to Windows settings, when Helvetica is not installed, Arial will be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet to make sure your website is using Helvetica instead of Arial (if possible):

```
body {
   font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
   font-weight: 300;
}
```

In addition there are many alternatives to Helvetica, if you need something free try [Google WebFonts](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/) , they have at least a few fonts that look more or less like Helvetica: Actor, Asap, Cabin, Droid Sans, Lato, Open Sans, PT Sans, Varela.

Comment: Arial [looks plenty enough like Helvetica](http://snth.net/~rlk/image/helvetica-vs-arial.png) to cover this without even resorting to further embeds. I think there's something else going on in this question. (Or it's just really badly stated.)

Comment: People who really care can really tell the difference, even if most people would consider that a little bit compulsive. Arial is *very* similar to Helvetica, but there are differences in the glyphs that get noticed by people who care, and there are differences in the hinting, so they flow a little differently.  Just saying...

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said. If you are using an actual font and not an image of a font, you can not force a font onto a system legally.

What you should do is use a proper CSS font-stack as shown in other answers and the computer will use the first font that it comes to that it has on the system.

Always put Helvetica before Arial, so that when available it will be chosen first. Helvetica and Arial DO look very similar, but people who care can tell the difference.

http://www.ironicsans.com/helvarialquiz/

Comment: Also: http://ilovetypography.com/2007/10/06/arial-versus-helvetica/ and http://www.marksimonson.com/notebook/view/how-to-spot-arial